# PHP cURL, Help creating an API Call Script

Tags: php, api, curl

I was wanting some help please to create a snippet of cURL to call an API.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

This is the API Call

```
POST https://api.passes.com/v1/templates/names/Member%20Card/pass
```

apparently they need the following sent

```
------------------------------330184f75e21
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="values"; filename="values.json"
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
}
------------------------------330184f75e21
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="icon"; filename="icon.png"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

imagedata
------------------------------330184f75e21
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="icon@2x"; filename="icon@2x.png"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

imagedata
```

I am not sure what to place in the cURL at all.

I have tried the following without success.

```
$url1 = 'https://api.passes.com/v1/templates/names/Test/pass';

$data1 = array("values" => '{"first":"John","last":"Doe"}','application/json',
                "strip" => '@../uploads/icon.png','application/octet-string','icon.png',
                "strip@2x" => '@../uploads/icon.png','application/octet-string','icon.png');

$auth1 = array(  "authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxx=",  "cache-control: no-cache",  "postman-token: xxxxxxxxx");

$ch1 = curl_init($url1);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data1);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $auth1);

$response1 = curl_exec($ch1);

echo $response1;
```

It replies with a response saying invalid JSON

If anyone can help that would be great.

Thanks

Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not write raw json string, but let PHP do it for you.

```
$values = array(
    'first' => 'John',
    'last' => 'Doe'
);

$data1 = array(
    'values' => json_encode($values),
    'strip' => '@../uploads/icon.png',
        'application/octet-string',
        'icon.png',
    'strip@2x' => '@../uploads/icon.png',
        'application/octet-string',
        'icon.png'
);
```

Comment: Ok so it means what you send is valid JSON format but invalid data structure from what they expect.